# Using "TouchDown" for a specific area with GestureListener from LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

Is it possible to register an input to a *specific area* of the screen (like say, a Texture Region) in LibGDX by using the Gesture Listener class?

I was using the touchDown method like so:

```
@Override
    public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        if(GameIsOver) {
          Restart();
        }

        if (GameIsNotOver) {
            if (x == RegionObject.getRegionX()){
            System.out.println("touched");
         }
    }


}
```

Where RegionObject is my Texture Region. It works for the first part (GameIsOver), since it registers any touch on the whole screen.

But I can't get it to work on a specific area.

Should I just use the InputMultiplexer? Or should I do something else entirely?

Is it possible at all with GestureListener/Detecter?

Comment: If you want to use gesture listener you can create a stage at your specific area and use gesture listener with that stage.

Comment: I set up my project without using scene2d. Will adding stage and actors at this point be difficult?

Comment: I don't know, how is your project set up?

Comment: I have a Game render class for the rendering, an input processer class for the input, etc. the project is set up like so (http://www.kilobolt.com/uploads/1/2/5/7/12571940/88999_orig.png?638)

Answer (score 0):

Any specific use of `GestureListener` ?

Touch can be detected by using `InputProcessor` or by using his adapter class `(InputAdapter)`

Specific Area need to be bound, You can use `Sprite`, that holds the geometry, color, and texture information for drawing.

```
Sprite sprite=new Sprite(textureRegion);

if(sprite.getBoundingRectangle().contains(x,y))
    Gdx.app.log("TAG","touch on particular area");
```